# Function $f$ evaluated at each term of a convergent sequence yields a constant number $C$. Let the limit be $L$. Does that mean that also $f(L)=C$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $ \left\{ a_n \right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ be a sequence of real numbers, such that $ \lim_{\substack{n\rightarrow\infty}}a_n=L $. Next, let $ f $ be a function from the real numbers to itself. If $ f(a_n) = C $ (constant) for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, does that mean that also $ f(L) = C $ ?

Comment: The set-theoretic definition of a function $f:A\to B$ is $any$ set $f$ of members of $A\times B$ such that for each $a\in A$ there is exactly one $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f.$ So a function $is$ its graph. But even set-theorists prefer to say $b=f(a)$ instead of $(a,b)\in f.$ This modern definition is very general, and without additional conditions on $f$ (e.g. continuity), no information about $f(L)$ can be inferred from the values of $f(a)$ for all or any $a\ne L.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous at $L$, the answer is yes. (See if you can prove this.)

If $f$ is not continuous at $L$, then not necessarily. A counterexample would be: Define the sequence $(a_n)$ by $a_n:=1/n$, so that $a_n\to 0=:L$, and take
$$f(x):=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if $x>0$}\\2 &\text{if $x\le0$}\end{cases}.
$$
Then $f(a_n)=1$ for all $n$ while $f(L)=2$.

Note, however, for the sequence $a_n:=-1/n$ we have $a_n\to L$, $f(a_n)=2$ for all $n$, and $f(L)=2$.